# Bootstrap Collapse Column fix Jump to Bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a bootstrap3 collpase (link "more") on the gray squares, but when clicking on the collapse of square 1 square 3 change with 4 and jumps to the bottom.

In square 2 it seems to work better.

**wrong**
[image]

**ok**
[image]

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: red; height: 350px;">
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
   <?php for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++): ?>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
       <div style="background-color: gray; height: 150px;">
         <?= $i +1; ?>
       </div>
       <a class="progress-description" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse<?= $i ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse<?= $i ?>">More</a>
         <div class="collapse" id="collapse<?= $i ?>">
            <div class="text-justify">
              DESCRIPTION
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
   <?php endfor; ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: Change the col-sm-12 to col-md-12.

Comment: @RohanRao not working, happen the same

Comment: How about col-lg-12?

Comment: @RohanRao this happens, https://i.ibb.co/tQw6fkK/Sem-T-tulo3.png (see the link, please), but it's not intended.

Comment: Hmm. In that case, the for loop might not work. You need to take two rows in the second column to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

wrap you for loop of div containing the description blocks in an another div having row class.

```
<div class="row">
// your existing for loop
</div>
```

Comment: not working, the result is similar to what I answered above.